# one arraylist to another arraylist?

Tags: android, arraylist, copy

I'm new to android..

I am coping one String arraylist values to another String arraylist, i want copy with out duplicates. please any one help me...

Thanks a lot..

> ```
>     public class Videoplayer extends Activity {
> private GridView girGridView;
> public static String hs = "";
> public static ArrayList<String> Array = new ArrayList<String>();
> public static ArrayList<String> resim_list=new ArrayList<String>();
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_videoplayer);
>     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
>     ArrayList<String> Array = bundle.getStringArrayList("string-array");
>     GridViewConfig.addImageUrls();
>     System.out.println("String Video"+ Array);
>     girGridView=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1_bir);
>     girGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this)); 
>     girGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>                     @Override
>                     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,long arg3) {
>                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), GridViewConfig.getResim_list().get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                              
>                     }
>             });
> }
>     public static class GridViewConfig {
>     public static ArrayList<String> resim_list=new ArrayList<String>();
>     public static ArrayList<String> getResim_list() {
>             return resim_list;
>     }
>     public void setResim_list(ArrayList<String> resim_list) {
>             GridViewConfig.resim_list = resim_list;
>     }
>     public static void addImageUrls() {
>             Set<String> hs = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Array);// set of unique elments
>         // LinkedHashSet maintains insertion order
>             resim_list.addAll(hs);
>      System.out.println("NEW RESIM_LIST" + resim_list);
> ```

How to do this???

Comment: check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public static ArrayList<String> Array = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> resim_list=new ArrayList<String>();
```

In your activity

```
    Array = bundle.getStringArrayList("string-array");
   // already Array is initalized. no need to initialize again
    GridViewConfig.addImageUrls();// call the add method
```

GridViewConfig class

```
    public static class GridViewConfig {
    public static ArrayList<String> resim_list=new ArrayList<String>();

    public static ArrayList<String> getResim_list() {
        return resim_list;
    }

    public void setResim_list(ArrayList<String> resim_list) {
        GridViewConfig.resim_list = resim_list;
    }

    public static void addImageUrls() {
        Set<String> hs = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Array);// set of unique elments 
        // LinkedHashSet maintains insertion order 
        resim_list.addAll(hs);
        for(int i=0;i<resim_list.size();i++)
        {
          System.out.println("NEW RESIM_LIST" + resim_list.get(i));

        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Declare this before onCreate()

```
public  ArrayList<String> Array = new ArrayList<String>();
public  ArrayList<String> resim_list=new ArrayList<String>();
```

In your onCreate()

```
Array = bundle.getStringArrayList("string-array");
addImageUrls();
```

Then define addImageUrls in your activity class as below

```
      public  void addImageUrls() {
        ArrayList<String> resim_list=new ArrayList<String>();
        Set<String> hs = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Array);// set of unique elments 
        // LinkedHashSet maintains insertion order 
        resim_list.addAll(hs);
        for(int i=0;i<resim_list.size();i++)
        {
          System.out.println("NEW RESIM_LIST" + resim_list.get(i));
        }   
      }
```

Array is declared with a class scope. No need to use static modifies. If you intend to use it in another class pass it using intent.

Answer (score 1):

Use, **Set Collection Class**,

```
Set<String> set  = new HashSet<String>(Array);
resim_list.addAll(set);
```

Now here `Set` will remove all duplicates values from your `ArrayList`.

Comment: Set set = new HashSet(Array);
      resim_list.addAll(set);
      System.out.println("RESIM_LIST" + resim_list);

Comment: Iterate through complete `resim_list` List. using `iterator` or `For-loop`.

Answer (score 0):

you can  make original array list
        class One{

```
   public static  ArrayList<String> Array in class One .
 }
```

and when want this array list in any other class simply  do

```
class Two {
          ArrayList<String> Array2 = One.Array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you don't get any duplicates, you could loop through "resim_list" and check "Array" if it contains the element in "resim_list"

```
for(String item: resim_list){
    if(Array.contains(item))
    {
         Array.remove(item);   
    }    
}
```

Then you could use the code in two of the other answers.

```
Set set = new HashSet(Array);
resim_list.addAll(set);
```

And you shouldn't have any duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

You can use addAll method.

```
//without duplicated, use Set
Set setTemp = new HashSet(Array);
resim_list.addAll(setTemp);
```

Comment: PO requested " i want to copy without duplicates"